# How to recover a deleted local group with specific SID

Tags: windows-server-2019, local, sid

Env: Windows Server 2019

1. Special software creates & configures a local user group called "app_users" with SID X
2. Without realising via a 'GPO replace', I accidentally deleted Local User group "app_users" with SID X
3. Thought I could re-create the the local user group "app_users" but it now has SID Y
4. What can I do to recover this original local user group with the original SID X (so that the software that use's it will function properly with the relevant security permissions)?

Or conversely is there a way to search and replace SID X with SID Y wherever it is assigned on components/objects/permissions/security etc?

My alternative is to reinstall the software but that will take a considerable amount of time on 20-30 machines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: reinstall the software instead wasting the time here is a fast and responsive solution inho

Comment: due to how the software works (very legacy), this could take 3 weeks...

Comment: I've read 20-30 minutenls, sorry about that mistake ;)

Comment: how ever, your still lacking on research. I've found a official tutorial on [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/identity/retore-deleted-accounts-and-groups-in-ad)

Comment: i think you've misunderstood what I'm asking, this is in reference to a Local User Group created on the local machine, not a domain user group, not a domain user.

Comment: then come over please with details which software is affected, what server is beeing used, and why are you using local groups instead of a active directory? [eve if here is ad meaned, you can not change the sid](https://serverfault.com/questions/53717/how-can-i-change-the-sid-of-a-user-account-in-the-active-directory) while it might technically possible, but it's against any practice to do so. I never seen a software that belongs on a sid instead of a group name